# Modify functionality of Parent class without rewrite in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Let's say I have an abstract class, called Logger:

```
public abstract class AbstractLogger {
public enum Levels {
    DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR
}

public void debug(String message) {
    Levels level = Levels.DEBUG;
    log(level, message);
}

public void info(String message) {
    Levels level = Levels.INFO;
    log(level, message);
}

public void warning(String message) {
    Levels level = Levels.WARNING;
    log(level, message);    }

public void error(String message) {
    Levels level = Levels.ERROR;
    log(level, message);    }

public void log(Levels level, String message) {}
```

}

And I also have classes that inherit this class, such as FileAppenderLogger:

```
public class FileAppenderLogger extends AbstractLogger {
private final Path logPath;

public FileAppender(Path logPath) {
    this.logPath = logPath;
    createLogFile();
}

private void createLogFile() {
    try {
        File logFile = new File(logPath.toString());
        if (logFile.createNewFile()) {
            System.out.println("File created: " + logFile.getName());
        } else {
            System.out.println("File already exists.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void log(Levels level, String message) {
    try {
        FileWriter myWriter = new FileWriter(this.logPath.toString());
        myWriter.write(message+"\n");
        myWriter.close();
        System.out.println("Successfully wrote to the file.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void debug(String message) {
    super.info(message);
}

@Override
public void info(String message) {
    super.info(message);
}

@Override
public void warning(String message) {
    super.warning(message);
}

@Override
public void error(String message) {
    super.error(message);
}
```

}

Now, let's say I need to extend Logger to support new Log level, such as "FATAL", and also extend its children, such as FileAppenderLogger to support it, without modify any of those classes, only extend them.
what could be the best practice for that (if I still want to preserve non generic methods such as ".info(String s)" or ".debug(String s))?
What design pattern may I use here?
I'm open for changes regard this problem.
Thank you!

Comment: Not really sure I understand your problem.  Do you not have access to the base class (`AbstractLogger`)?

Comment: I wasn't clear, I meant without modify any of them

Comment: Well... you do actually have to write code.

Comment: I know, But do you have any idea how to add functionality without modifying the main abstract class?

Comment: @Asaf rewrite your question making it clear what is it that you are trying to do.

Comment: @Asaf: If you want to add functionality to class A, why do you not want to modify class A? Are there any existing classes that you'd be willing and able to modify?

Answer (score 1):

Simply add it to `AbstractLogger`:

```
public abstract class AbstractLogger {
  public enum Levels {
      DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, ERROR, /* added */ FATAL,
  }

  public void fatal(String message) {
    log(Levels.FATAL, message);
  }
}
```

Given that the types that extend `AbstractLogger` all already implement the `log` method, then 'things will just work' - possibly some of the implementations cannot deal with the fact that a new log level has now appeared. Assuming they were appropriately programmed, they'll throw. Your `FileAppenderLogger` class, for example, would just continue to work without requiring any change or even recompilation.

The key design pattern to make this work is that all those non-generic methods such as `.error(x)` are light wrappers that all send the data to a single method that does the real work - `log`. But, you already do that.

NB: Reinventing the wheel is a bad idea. Logging frameworks already exist, use an existing one instead.

NB2: Idiomatic java dictates you call your enum types the singular - it should be `Level`, not `Levels`. The type name describes, well, a type name. It's called `String`, not `Strings`, because an instance of `java.lang.String` represents one string. The class itself represents all strings, but that doesn't mean it should be called `Strings`. Similarly, an instance of the `Levels` enum represents a single level. Hence, it should be named `Level`, not `Levels`.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear, I meant without modifying any of the classes.

Comment: You obviously can't, then. You can't make methods appear without changing the source short of hackery you don't want to engage in.

Comment: I know I can't make methods apear without changing the source, I am asking if I can create new classes that extend their functinality

Comment: @Asaf you have written both "without modifying any of the classes" and "without modifying the main abstract class".  Hopefully you see a problem here.

Comment: I can tell the confusion, thank you. I meant as if I don't have access to edit those classes, but I want to extend their functionality. and don't worry I don't try to reinvent the wheel, only to improve my JAVA skills. thank you

Comment: You can't change the enum, therefore you can't do any of this if you can't change these source files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `enum` for level, you can make class `LogLevel` and make classes that extend it, for example `LogLevelError, LogLevelFatal`, then in log method: `this.logLevel.log(message);`. Of course, it look strange, but this is the way I see to add new log levels. Also, as said by @rzwitserloot :"NB: Reinventing the wheel is a bad idea. Logging frameworks already exist, use an existing one instead". They are much faster, optimized, and 'time-tested'.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** add more values to your enum, that's not possible in java. I would suggest to either use a `String` for levels, or declare your own `Level` class, so you can add more levels.

```
public class Level {

    private final String levelName;

    //getter, etc.
}
```

To extend the functionality of your `AbstractLogger`, without modifying it, you can wrap it in another class and declare the additional methods, `fatal()` in this case.

```
public class ExtendedLogger extends AbstractLogger {

    private final AbstractLogger abstractLogger;

    public ExtendedLogger(AbstractLogger abstractLogger) {
        this.abstractLogger = abstractLogger;
    }

    @Override
    public void debug(String message) {
        abstractLogger.debug(message);
    }

    //info, warning and rest of methods

    @Override
    public void log(Levels level, String message) {
        abstractLogger.log(level, message);
    }

    public void fatal(String message) {
        //implement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First: logger libraries are numerous, and the first reform was the introduction of `java.util.Logger` to unify things a bit. Still not the dead of the other logging libraries.

Then came - especially for libraries - the underestimated **`System.Logger`**: a Logger façade that can be discover logging implementations. This allows publishing a library, use Logging, but leave the actual logging library choice to the library user.

So in that context meddling in class hierarchies and enum constants is counter-productive to say the least.

What you can do is a specific configuration, say for some packages, implement a specific file handler (`FileHandler`, `Handler`), and reserve ERROR for your own FATALISH when using `*Exception` classes or such.

Though seemingly simple, using `FileWriter` in the Logger child was not intended to be done as such. You should leave it to configuring the usage to your own `Handler` class.

Unfortunately **the** solution does not exist. You'll better write a prototype to test your specific configuration.